# How to render <base> tag in wicket framework

Tags: java, wicket

What are the ways to render base tag using wicket framework?

In JSP I can do something like this:

```
<base href="${pageScope.contextPath}/" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In YourPage.html:

```
<head>
   ...
   <base wicket:id="base"/>
   ...
</head>
```

In YourPage.java:

```
WebComponent base = new WebComponent("base");
add(base);
base.add(new AttributeModifier("href", "<the url>"));
```

Comment: how about to use the  `WebMarkupContainer` is that wrong or any difference ?

Comment: `WebMarkupContainer` assumes that the component may have children. `WebComponent` is designed for leaf HTML elements, like `<base/>`, `<input/>`, `<img/>`, etc. Using `WebMarkupContainer` won't do any harm!